# Create List or Cast by List from Class name

Tags: java, list, generics

I have generic class, and I want to create a `List` or cast by `List`. I only have the class type. What I want to get is:

```
public class CustomerDao extends BaseDao<Customer> implements ICustomerDao {

    private Class<Customer> entityClass;

    public CustomerDao(Class<Customer> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void getCustomers() {
        List<***> list = (List<***>)getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass).list();
    }
}
```

Now how can I use the field `entityClass` to create the `List<***> list`? Is it possible?

I can use `List<Customer> list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass).list();`, but I am want to learn different way.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast by `List`"?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my code, where you can find the cast by `List`.

Comment: Why would you *want* to cast to (not by) `List`, when you don't know the type? You're just declaring a local variable... what would you then do with it?

Comment: Another way? Do you mean that you want to do manually what you can achieve with the use of generics? Also, just a comment, is `getCustomers()` intended to be void?

Comment: @JonSkeet in the code it seem to be local variable, also I can only return `List` without any type. that should work. I am willing to know if it is possible or not.

Comment: @Gamb yes you are right, the return type shouldn't be void. It is just a sample piece of code. How can I achieve it by generics? Adding generic argument to the class declaration?

Comment: @TapasBose: It's very hard to help you when we don't know what you're trying to *achieve* with the code. "It is just a sample piece of code" isn't useful when the sample doesn't demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are trying to implement a type-specific DAO (for your Customer entity), derived from an abstract, generic Base DAO. If indeed that is what you are trying to accomplish then there is no need for generics at all:

```
public class CustomerDao extends BaseDao<Customer> implements ICustomerDao {

    public CustomerDao() {
        super(Customer.class);
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        final List<Customer> list = (List<Customer>) getSessionFactory().
            getCurrentSession()
           .createCriteria(Customer.class).list();
    }
}
```

Its been awhile since I used the Hibernate API's, but I dont think you need the typecast to `List<Customer>` either.

Answer (score 1):

That would be meaningless.
Generics only exist at compile-time.

Instead, you should make your entire class generic.

Comment: Or, make the entire class specific to his generic parameter type (`Customer`).